# Comparing two populations with different amount of 'categories'. Need to know by how much (%) 'category' A has increased

Tags: method-comparison

Very new to statistics and I don’t know the correct terms or what to Google! In 2021 x amount of visas were refused for 5 different reasons. In 2022 y amount of visas were refused for 6 different reasons. One of these reasons is Insufficient Funds and refusals for this reason has increased dramatically since 2021. I need to say it has increased by …%, but as there are 6 reasons in 2022 compared to 5 in 2021, it seems obvious that this will skew the result and I need to compensate, but I have no idea how. I'd appreciate a step by step guide on how to work this out as I have found a number of methods on the internet but don't have enough expertise to know what the correct solution is. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to CV, A.Herron! I was puzzled about your question - stumbled upon you "need to compensate" for the number of variables. But this could be just a misunderstanding because of different terminology use. Could you give us perhaps more details about your data? What are the variables (roughly), how big are your samples (also roughly)?

Comment: Let's back up here. A _variable_ is in spreadsheet terms usually whatever is naturally a column in a dataset. I suspect that you're variously talking about (perhaps) the number of observations you have, or the number of distinct (different) values you have, or something else. In short, this isn't clear without a concrete example. Don't try to abstract from the problem while you're still learning basic terminology.

Comment: One reason has increased from 0% to something% of 
 the refusals in 2022.  The other reasons have necessarily changed % incidence. Not a problem so far as I can see. Nothing is "skewed" there and there is nothing to compensate for.

Comment: I think your edit made it actually much clearer - using the word "variable" instead of "category" was the reason for confusion. Here is a suggestion what you could do: divide the percentage of category A in the years with 6 reasons by the  total percentage of all old reasons (A to E). This only makes sense if the new reason has no overlap with the old ones. Could you yell us which were the reasons, in short?

Comment: I just upvoted the question because it seems relevant for statistical modelling and interpretation of results. It still will benefit from more clarification ;-)